# Firebase Cloud Functions - Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have something like this:

```
const promises = [];

    l = niz.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if(niz[i].length === 0) {
          continue;
      }

      promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options));
    }

   return Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
        return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
        //return resolve(); 
    }).then(() => {
        return resolve();
    });
```

but always I have crash in firebase logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>       at cleanupTokens (/user_code/index.js:193:20)
>       at Promise.all.then (/user_code/index.js:169:20)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Response is:

> response:  [ { results: [ [Object] ],
>       canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
>       failureCount: 0,
>       successCount: 1,
>       multicastId: 5591935326806715000 } ]
>
> response: undefined

cleanup is:

```
function cleanupTokens(response, tokens) {

// For each notification we check if there was an error.
const tokensToRemove = {};

console.log('response: ', response);

console.log('response: ', JSON.stringify(response.results));

response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
       const error = result.error;

       if (error) {
         console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);

         // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
         if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
             error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered' ||
             error.code === 'messaging/invalid-recipient') {

           tokensToRemove[`/tokens/${tokens[index]}/g`] = null;
           tokensToRemove[`/tokens/${tokens[index]}/l/0`] = null;
           tokensToRemove[`/tokens/${tokens[index]}/l/1`] = null;
         }
       }
   });

   return admin.database().ref().update(tokensToRemove);
}
```

Any help with cleanup tokens?

Comment: It looks like `response.results` is not an array. Can you replace `console.log('response: ', response.results);` with `console.log('response: ', JSON.stringify(response.results));` and add that log to your question.

Comment: off course, it's undefined

Comment: Interesting, since your original log showed `results: [ [Object]` which seems to indicate that `results` is an array. But if it is `undefined` you should check for that before calling `forEach` on it. So `if (response.results) { response.results.forEach(...`

Answer (score 0):

You chose to send each notification separately to each user, making the response become "wrapped" as a singleton of response, and each response is also a singleton of itself - making it weird to access (`response[0].results.foreach` should probably work)

But even then, you'd have only 1 item to go trough, because you made each notification to be sent individually. I believe it is much more efficient to have a 1 time `sendToDevice()` request to all of the relevant tokens, instead of sending them separately.

Consider changing your first code to this:

```
//const promises = [];
var tokens = [];

l = niz.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  //if(niz[i].length === 0) {
  if(niz[i].length > 0) //I guess those are your relevant tokens
      tokens.push(niz[i]); //Fill in the relevant tokens
}

//promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options));

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options)
.then(response => {
    return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
})
.then(() => {
    return resolve();
});

//return Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
//    return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
//    //return resolve(); 
//}).then(() => {
//    return resolve();
//});
```

The rest of your code should work after this change.

(Few credits to @[Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572001/firebase-cloud-functions-response-undefined#comment90110882_51572001) for his comment - the JSON log helped determining the issue)

**EDIT:**

Regarding your comment, if each niz[i] item is an array itself, you could do this:

```
const promises = [];

l = niz.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if(niz[i].length === 0) {
      continue;

  //promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options));

  var newPromise = return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options)
  .then(response => {
    return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
  })
  .then(() => {
      return resolve();
  });

  promises.push(newPromise);

}

return Promise.all(promises);

//return Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
//    return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
//    //return resolve(); 
//}).then(() => {
//    return resolve();
//});
```

Comment: sendToDevice has limit of 1000 per one request, so I divide my tokens into arrays of size 999 ...

Comment: your code works! Thanks! Now, I must go, will return for couple of hours :)

Comment: I think last code about sending is wrong because tokens array can be more than 1000 and sentToDevice has limit to 1000 per single request ...

Comment: Earlier you said that you divided each inner array into a size of 999... so assuming that, it should work

Comment: I think tokens should be replaced by niz[i] in sendToDevice, otherwise niz[i] is never used? btw "niz" is "array" but in Serbian :)

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've edited my answer, missed it earlier. Oh, and nice to know about the "niz" term :)